# Bootstrap essentials (Bootstrap extension) "not working" in Angular

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I create a web application based on ASP .Net Core and Angular. I also use the Bootstrap library. I wanted to add an extension to Bootstrap - Bootstrap Essentials. The problem is that the classes from this library don't work for me. I downloaded the extension using the command `npm install bootstrap-essentials` . Then I added the styles and scripts file paths (in the `angular.json`  file).

This is what the paths to the needed files in `angular.json` look like:

[image: angular.json file and paths to bootstrap-essentials files]

My goal was to use the library to make a side slide for mobile devices. I copied the code from the documentation (I didn't change anything).

Documentation code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-slide-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-slide offcanvas">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

According to the documentation, I should get such a bar after pressing the hamburger button:

[image: Result from documentation]

But instead I get this:

[image: My result]

It looks like the style and script file is not visible to Angular.

I looked at the folders and the files are actually there. The strange thing is that when using classes from pure Bootstrap everything works fine. This additional library does not work. I don't get any errors or warnings in the console on the browser. Additionally, when compiling with `ng serve --open`, it doesn't show any errors (so the given paths are valid because they exist). Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the documentation (bootstrap-essentials) of the Bootstrap extension in more detail. It turns out that this extension was written with Bootstrap 3 in mind. It is not compatible with 4 (Bootstrap 4 is in my project). I have downgraded to Bootstrap 3 and it actually works with that version.